# How do I get Google Analytics data into a CMS without asking the user to authenticate?

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have a web application backend for my clients web site. Authorised staff can log in to the backend and view data. 
I want to pull some data from Google Analytics to be viewed in the backend, but GA seems to insist that the user is logged in to their Google account themselves using OAuth2
I want to be able to authenticate the server not the user. They already have permission and it seems unnecessary and possibly intrusive to ask them to link their Google accounts to the GA account and possibly even have to create one first.

The server already has to supply a client id, client secret and an api key, so it's not as if there isn't already an authenticated connection.

I'm guessing that there must be a way to pass the Google Analytics account credentials to OAuth2 somehow but I am not that familiar with OAuth2 
Is this possible and how would it be done. A simple example or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated

There are similar questions around but the ones I have found do not answer my question in the way I need.

Comment: It should be possible. Who is the owner of the Google Analytics account?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to store the authentication, but you may be able to use [Google Analytics Super Proxy for your needs.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy)  At the very least you can see its code on how it stores the authentication.

You authenticate once, input the data you need scheduled from the GA Reporting API, then take the data feed and use it to build charts in your intranet. Any user can view those charts without needing to login to GA themselves.